# Complete removal and fresh install of python on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, ubuntu-12.04

This is embarrassing to admit, but I just continue to struggle with setting up my Python environment on an Ubuntu install.

Sometimes I get it to work fine. But here's the problem:

I feel like whenever I sit down to do some hobby hacking on a python project, I end up spending hours on end just trouble shooting inconsistencies with my python installation. Right now I keep getting an error message of:

```
ImportError: cannot import name urandom
```

when trying to import a module called googleplaces (https://github.com/slimkrazy/python-google-places).

But it's always something that causes me to go on an endless snipe hunt for the proper configuration of this that or the other.

I just want to work on the project, not plumb around endlessly in forums.

Which brings me to my point: How do I completely nuke my existing python setup (including virtualenv, pip, easy_install, etc. etc.) and just start from a completely clean slate? I have already tried reinstalling everything python from synaptic, but no success, still getting error.

**UPDATE:** I've reinstalled virtualenv and that seems "ok" so far. Found that my import error is a permissions problem, if I import in the interactive using sudo, it passes fine. How should I be correcting my permissions so I don't have to run sudo?  (Probably close this and start a new question.)

Comment: Instead of doing that (which will lead to other problems later), considering using virtual environments correctly.

Comment: I am totally with you, but my virtualenv is part of the culprit here. It's broken since updating to 12.04 and the prevailing advice to run virtualenv in my /PATH/TO/virtualenv has not been useful to me.

Comment: You can simply delete the virtualenv directory; and upgrade the virtual environment from apt. `apt-get install python-virtualenv`

Comment: If it's hosed, reinstalling Ubuntu would seem to be the way to go.

Comment: @tripleee yeah, it might be time for that, every upgrade comes with new problems, might be time to clear out the ubuntu sludge that builds up with each one.